# Is there a D&D 3.5e equivalent to the Death Field psionic power from 2nd edition?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics, hit-points

D&D 2nd edition's Psionic class has a psionic power called Death Field. That power allows character to sacrifice half of his hitpoints to deal damage to all living things in some radius around character.

Is there non Psionic effect (spell, supernatural ability, magic item...) that could mimic such a power in DnD 3.5 for a non Psionic character?

Comment: While an expert in both *3.5* and *2nd Edition* psionics would be best suited to answering this question, many *3.5* experts who aren't also *2nd Edition* experts would probably really like to help. If more details were included about the power—range, damage, whether its a science or whatever (my *2e* psionics nomenclature is fuzzy), and so on—, I'm certain folks would try to find an equivalent.

Comment: Also, please source which book the power came from?

Comment: @nijineko: It's from the Complete Psionics Handbook, page 52 (there weren't a lot of sources for Psionic Powers in 2E, and almost all the rest came from the Dark Sun supplements Dragon Kings and The Will and the Way).

Comment: It's a psychometabolic science, they burn 40 PSPs (a *very* high cost relative to other powers, typically initial costs are between 5 and 25 PSPs), choose to sacrifice any number of their remaining HP (not just "half"), and if the power goes off (roll below Con-8), they lose those HP (no save), and every other living thing within 20 yards must save vs. death or lose the same number of HP (save prevents all damage). It's specifically called out as being an "evil" power (non-evil psionicists become evil as a side-effect of exploring the dark parts of their psyches necessary to fuel this power).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### *Affinity Field, Pain*, from the Complete Psionic

The 9th level power *Affinity Field, Pain* has somewhat similar effects, enough to guess that it might be the spiritual descendant of the Death Field power.

In short, when the field is active, negative conditions that affect you, affect others in range. This means you can take damage,  or get cursed, and get healed, but only the effects deemed negative will be shared.

As a bonus, you can pick and choose who gets affected within the area, and it is not considered evil for alignment purposes.

---

Note that you will also need the Expanded Psionics Handbook or the SRD, as this power references the power *Affinity Field* from those sources for its base effects.

In summary, *Affinity Field* shares all effects, both positive and negative, and doesn't allow one to discriminate targets. Handy against undead if you have a reliable source of positive energy, among other tricks.

Also note that in the case of either power, you have to be actually affected in order for a given effect to be shared, immunity to something prevents the sharing of that thing.

---

With regards to accessing such a power by a non-psionicist, using the magic item creation rules to make a magic or psionic item that has an activation by key word or activation by use would be the most straightforward method.

You will most likely be using one of the following to estimate the cost:

> Single use, use-activated = Power/Spell level × caster level × 50 gp
>
> Command word or thought = Power/Spell level × caster level × 1,800 gp
>
> Use-activated or continuous = Power/Spell level × caster level × 2,000 gp

A 9th level power requires a 17th level Psion to manifest at minimum.

This yields a base cost of 7,650gp for the single use version, 275,400gp for the command word or thought version, and 306,000gp for the use anytime version.

However, magic and psionic items are limited to 200,000gp max base cost, so some limitation must be applied to the top two in order to bring the cost down to below the limit.

Regarding activation method, I suggest having to daub or splash the activating character's blood on the item. Theatrically and thematically appropriate.

Comment: My question was not clear, i would like to know about non Psionic power that could mimic Death field. Question is now edited to reflect that.

Comment: @tbalaz actually, your edit just asks for a power for a non-psionic character, not a non-psionic effect. Which is your intent?

Comment: intent was to have a non psionic charater that can reduce it self to near death -9HP  and deal damage equal to hitpoints lost to everyone around himself.

Comment: @tbalaz most psionic items can be used by non-psionic characters such as weapons, armor, skins, universal items and I think crowns. However I see my answer is still incomplete as per your intent. I have the share damage part nailed down, but not the damage to one's self part. I'll add to my answer after I think a bit more.

Comment: Oh, non-psionic effect now? I won't be familiar enough to answer that, though the concept I present works. I'll let another answer it, I only play psionics these days.

Comment: the concept presented is excellent, thing is, we do not have Psionics.  DM ruled that we can't play them. If he would allow that they exist as NPC-s, than i could try to find one i and create magic item as you suggested. I'll check that with him.

Comment: Odd considering that the 3.x psionic system is somewhat better balanced than the magic system, sigh. There is always the rules for researching new spells, simply make a new spell that functions the same as the power, or even research the 2nd ed spell, for that matter!

Answer (score 2):

#### After some more research, I found out that there is an official 3.5 version of the *Death Field* power.

While this is still a psionic power, it should be fairly trivial to convert it to a spell using other spells that have been converted to psionic powers (Secrets of Sarlona), the spellpowers rules from the web article, and perhaps the Unearthed Arcana spell point rules as guidance.

The power is found in the Dark Sun core book on Athas.org, the site designated as official by WotC at: http://athas.org/products/ds3

The pdf is named "DS3_r7".